# Updating an existing entity with objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I try to update an existing entity but when using `Ref.create`, the cached value is used. The client objects are:

```java
public class RealEstatePropertyAPI {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private AddressAPI address;
}

public class AddressAPI {
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String country;
}
```

The corresponding object on the server side:

```java
@Entity
public class RealEstateProperty {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Parent
    private Ref<Owner> owner;
    private String name;
    @Load
    private Ref<Address> address;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String country;
}
```

I have a method to convert from the client objects to the server one:

```java
public static RealEstateProperty fromAPI(RealEstatePropertyAPI api,
        Owner owner) {
    RealEstateProperty property = new RealEstateProperty();
    property.setId(api.getId());
    property.setName(api.getName());
    property.setOwner(owner);
    if (api.getAddress() != null) {
        Address address = AddressConverter.fromAPI(api.getAddress());
        String x = address.getStreet();
        property.setAddress(address);
        String y = property.getAddress().getStreet();
        System.out.println(x.equals(y));
    }
    return property;
}

public static Address fromAPI(AddressAPI api) {
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setId(api.getId());
    address.setStreet(api.getStreet());
    address.setCity(api.getCity());
    address.setState(api.getState());
    address.setZip(api.getZip());
    address.setCountry(api.getCountry());
    return address;
}
```

The issue is in `RealEstateProperty.fromAPI`, `property.setAddress(address);` is supposed to set the new `Address` but it's not. Why `x.equals(y)` returns false?

The method:

```java
public void setAddress(Address value) {
    this.address = Ref.create(value);
}
```

A related question about updating an entity. Does the following call updates both the `RealEstateProperty` and its child `Address`?

```java
public void update(RealEstateProperty property) {
    ofy().save().entity(property);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the "Additional Considerations" of the Refs section of this document:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities

Refs do not hold the entity value; they simply hold the key and let you load the value directly out of the session (or datastore if it isn't in the session). If you want to persist a new version of an address, you need to save() it explicitly.

Also: There can be no cascading save() of Refs because Refs do not hold entity objects! They are just "pointers".